# State pension from UK when a moving back to Spain after working only 10y in UK

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, pension, spain, pension-plan

I am a Spanish citizen who has been living in UK for the past 7 years. During this period I have always worked here and I haven't received any income from Spain.

I have also regularly contributed to a pension scheme that my company has setup and where the company contributes as well.

The question I have is what happens to my state pension contributions and my personal pension scheme in the event that I will leave the UK before I actually start getting retirement benefits?

For simplicity, let's say I am 35 and I will stay here in UK other 3 years (so a total of 10 years of contributions in UK) and I decide to move back to Spain to work the remaining years until retirement.

When I retire, will I be eligible for a state pension from the UK even if I am then in Spain? And would that cumulate to the one I will get from Spain?

I guess my personal pension scheme won't be a problem and I should be entitled to get the all money out as I want based on UK rules even if I am in Spain at that point.

Answer (score 2):

After 10 working/qualifying years in the UK you will receive an UK pension as things currently stand. The amount will increase to the full amount as you accumulate more qualifying years.

https://www.gov.uk/new-state-pension/how-its-calculated

If you take it abroad, it may not be index-regulated, however, which seems rather unfair, at least for individuals.

Comment: Hi, if the pension is not index-regulated that means is not getting adjusted by inflation? The link https://www.gov.uk/state-pension-if-you-retire-abroad/rates-of-state-pension suggests that there is an increase in case of Spain.

Comment: For the time being it is written in the section _State Pension and benefits_ on the page [https://www.gov.uk/guidance/living-in-the-eu-prepare-for-brexit](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/living-in-the-eu-prepare-for-brexit) that uprating is only guaranteed until 2023. It may of course be continued, but they haven't decided yet as far as I understand.

Comment: @nsandersen It’s not something the UK government can decide unilaterally. It will uprate pensions only as part of a bilateral agreement where Spain agrees to do the same for its pensioners living in the UK. Which I expect they will do, since there are far more UK pensioners in Spain than vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

> [...]
>
> When I retire, will I be eligible for a state pension from the UK even if I am then in Spain? [...]

Probably.

> [...] And would that cumulate to the one I will get from Spain?
>
> [...]

Likely so.

> [...] I guess my personal pension scheme won't be a problem and I should be entitled to get the all money out as I want based on UK rules even if I am in Spain at that point.

Very likely.

And you'd input such stuff in your *modelo 100* because law will likely demand something similar to current *Ley 35/2006, de 28 de noviembre, del Impuesto sobre la Renta de las Personas Físicas*, which is *[...] renta [...] **con independencia del lugar donde se hubiesen producido** [...]*. Unless you are somehow eligible to the *IRNR* law or any other future replacing it.